# Clearing char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sockets, tcp

I have declared `char data[101];` and after that read message from socket into it(server - client communication). After the message is displayed on screen I want to clear/empty that char array. I tried `memset(data, 0, sizeof(data))` and `bzero(data, sizeof(data));` And I think it still didn't clear it. At the output after receiving the first message I also get some weird characters: ��|V� and after them also the message is shown. Now I don't know if that is from clients or servers side. I tried to clear it on both but the result isn't any different.

This is how I send message:

```
char data[101];
read(0, data, 101);
dprintf(socket_fd, data);
bzero(data, sizeof(data));
```

Comment: That's certainly the way to set an array to all zeroes. But you need to show some actual code, in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), for this to be answerable.

Comment: Perhaps your program *sending* the data doesn't care about the string terminator? Does it use `sizeof` instead of `strlen` when calling `write` or `send`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm am using sizeof yes

Comment: If you're sending text, you have to make sure it is properly terminated as a string. It appears your data isn't terminated as a string. Also remember that if you use TCP it's a streaming protocol without message boundaries, and you might not receive a whole message in a single `read` or `recv` call.

Comment: Where is the memset() or bzero() line?

Comment: @Nguaial Forgot to copy it with it. Added now

Comment: It's a bit too late to zero out an array **after** you have sent it, innit?

Comment: Concur with @n.m.  - bzero() should be before read().

Comment: `char data[101 = "";`  is all needed.  Don't need memset() nor bzero().

Comment: @Nguaial this worked. Thanks!

Comment: ...and still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another alternative  solution

```
//Declare and initialize to NUL characters.
char data[101] ="";  

//fgets() will take care of out of boundary issue.
 if (fgets(stdin, data, sizeof(data))
    dprintf(socket_fd, "%s", data);  // Send the data
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you show is very problematic:

```
char data[101];
read(0, data, 101);
dprintf(socket_fd, data);
```

There are three major problems with it:

1. You don't check for errors, which means if the `read` call fails you will send uninitialized data.
2. You don't terminate the input as a string, which means you might go out of bounds when sending.
3. If the input contains `printf` formatting sequences then `dprintf` will attempt to read arguments that doesn't exist and you will have *undefined behavior* (and a really big security hole).

The following code should fix all of the above:

```
char data[101];  // Place for a 100-character string, plus terminator

ssize_t bytes_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, data, sizeof(data) - 1);  // -1 since we need space for terminator

// Make sure the read call went okay
if (bytes_read > 0)
{
    // There was no error or end-of-file
    data[bytes_read] = '\0';  // Terminate as a string

    dprintf(socket_fd, "%s", data);  // Send the data
}
```

---

On the receiving side you of course need to add error checking when receiving the data, attempt to receive one byte *less* than the data-buffer size, and terminate the data-buffer before printing it.

Comment: Why not use `fgets()`? This will automatically check out of boundary issue in case input characters exceed 101.  Is there a reason to use `read()`?  Thanks

Comment: This is the only sane solution presented.  Not unusually, another one with a cycle-wasting 'zero all the buffer even though you are about to load it' answer has been accepted.